# Multithreading for JDBC operations

Tags: java, multithreading, jdbc, spring-batch

I have a requirement where I need to create a JAVA application which will read data from 52 database tables, copy all data which is more than 3 years old to flat files (either csv, txt files), delete these data from tables and store these files on a SFTP server. The database in this case is Sybase ASE 15 version.

Also I need to restore this data in temporary tables when certain reports are to be prepared involving the above archived data.

If I make this application a single threaded application, it will take many hours to complete the task. So I need to make it multi-threaded.

Please suggest should I use only core java or any framework like spring batch. And how to achieve multi-threading in both the cases.

Comment: You're assuming without proof that multithreading it will make it faster. Test and measure.

Comment: KISS https://www.scopeforge.de/cb/wiki/3290

Comment: Use Spring batch. It will be more easier and faster

Comment: Well, in my case there are 52 tables, from which I can figure out the dependency so that those data will be managed by same thread and other dependencies by different threads. So I guess multithreading should make it faster.

Comment: What do you mean by dependency?

Comment: Multithreading will only help you if your task is CPU-bound, and from your description that sounds highly unlikely. You can't increase database and filesystem throughput with multithreading; you surely can *decrease* it, though.

Comment: dependency meaning tables with one to many and many to many relations

Comment: So if I avoid multithreading, then should I pursue core java or spring batch for this application

Comment: Nothing will gain you performance over plain, pure Java and JDBC.

Comment: I'm with those that question that multi-threading will help.  With Sybase each thread will need its own connection because its TDS protocol does not allow more than one active statement on a single connection.  And if most of your time is eaten by moving data across the network then your extra threads will sit idle waiting on the network unless you have multiple network cards in both machines.  I question this approach in general.  Why move the data about of DB in the first place.  Why not just move it to some new, read-only table and then report on that?